# Where is the definition of `Vue.component`?

Tags: vuejs2

We can define Vue component by:

```
Vue.component('element-name', {})
```

But where is source of method definition of `Vue.component`? I've spent hours on reading source files from https://github.com/vuejs/vue, but still can't find it.

Comment: This is the interface for component classes: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/flow/component.js

Comment: @Phiter Yes, there is an interface of `Component`, but where is the definition of method `Vue.component`?

Comment: @Freewind you can find definition of vue component by pressing F12 in visual studio code.